# Failed to Fetch error in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-api

We have a website and I've started implementing the fetch API instead of using jquery ajax, to start moving away from jquery and towards vanilla.

Every now and again I am getting an error where the fetch API is throwing an error.  I know this because I have set it up to send me an email if there are any errors thrown.  However, the error is not very descriptive.  It just says "Failed to fetch".  What does this mean?

Please note that this error is only happening some of the time.  This function with this url is being triggered hundreds, if not thousands of times a day, and I'm getting the error maybe once or twice a day.

Here is the javascript:

```
    async function fetchSimple(url, data = null, attempts = 0) {
        
        try {

            var response = await fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                body: data,
                headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                var responseJSON = await response.json();
                return responseJSON.d;
            } else {
                throw new Error(`Status: ${response.status}, StatusText ${response.statusText}`);
            }

        } catch (error) {
            attempts++;
            if (attempts == 1)
                fetchSimple(url, data, attempts);
            else {
                alert(`Failed to ${url}\n\nError Message: ${error.message}\n\nAn email logging the error details has been sent to the development team`);
                sendErrorLogEmail2(url, error.message, data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an error report I got over email:
Subject: Failed to /Yazzoo/Product.aspx/BuildProductDesignPositionsSectionUI

error: Failed to fetch

dataJSON: { "productId":24999 }

browser:{"name":"Chrome","version":"118","screenType":"mobile"}

Comment: This seems to be one issue, recursive calls in an await. I think you need `if (attempts == 1) return fetchSimple(url, data, attempts);`

Comment: Is the data stringified when you pass it to the fetchSimple?

Comment: If sendErrorLogEmail2 is async, you need to await it. Also alert is a blocker. Maybe update a page element insted?

Comment: it's awaited.  Also attempts is defaulted to 0 when I call it apart from the one time I want to "retry" it, which only happens inside the function.

Comment: also I did say this:

"Please note that this error is only happening some of the time. This function with this url is being triggered hundreds, if not thousands of times a day, and I'm getting the error maybe once or twice a day."

Answer (score 0):

There's a multitude of reasons that a fetch request returns 'Failed to fetch'.

The most likely reason the fetch fails sometimes is due to a network interruption. These things happen, and you need to deal with them accordingly.

Other reasons can include:

1. CORS error
2. Wrong URL
3. Wrong Protocol
4. Wrong Method was used.

The developer tools of your browser should give you more information on why a fetch request fails. Unfortunately, there's not a less generic error message included in the error object.

If you're interested, the Fetch standard lists all possible reasons a TypeError can occur (which are a lot of possible reasons): https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method

Comment: Sounds like a network interruption due to the intermittent nature of the error.  The other issues would happen every time.  It would be good if they could explicitly tell us that in the error message